# Zapier giving error on connection with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, zapier, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect my mongodb account to zapier, I have successfully connected it but when it comes to finding the collections of my specified database it is giving me the below error:

[image: Here is the image showing the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to ensure that the IP is whitelisted and has a public-facing IP address:

https://zapier.com/apps/mongodb/help#is-your-database-ip-restricted

If that doesn't work, you should check the version of MongoDB that you're using in the above Zap. Unfortunately, Zapier isn't currently able to support MongoDB versions above 3.0.

Comment: I think the problem is with the version than because i have allowed access from anywhere in my ip whitelist tab so that shouldn't be a problem i guess.